# Can't boot up laptop. Screen glitches out

Tags: boot, laptop, display, hardware-failure

My dad's  Dell 1525 Laptop screen goes all glitchy and freezes after about 20 seconds after boot.

This a video showing what happens
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NtoTpDAEzMY

I've tried the following:

- Reset Bios  to default settings
- Ran full diagnostics from Bios which came back with no errors
- Ran LCD diagnostics which was fine.  It showed all colors and bars correctly
- Replace RAM with RAM from another laptop that I know works
- Replace hardrive with hard drive from another laptop I know works
- Try to boot without battery in
- Boot up from Ubuntu DVD. Screen glitches and freezes just like in Windows
- I don't hear any beeps to from the machine to suggest a motherboard issue

Any ideas on what the issue is or other things I can investigate?

Comment: The motherboard has dedicated circuitry for generating the screen image. I'd say some parts within this circuitry is broken, with those parts not in use in those display mode(s) which is still working.

Comment: The lines on your screen look exactly same as mine when my discrete graphic card partially stopped working. My lines were vertical. My screen ran normal in Safe mode for sometime. I understood that it was a graphic card issue.

Comment: Video link is broken (only shows an ! where the video should be)

Answer (score 1):

Try to restart the laptop in SAFE MODE
If the same thing does not happen then it is pointing towards a hardware VGA issue.
[How to start Windows in Safe Mode or Safe Mode with Networking](http://support.eset.com/kb2268/?locale=en_US)